# Why does getElementById work but not getElementByClassName?

Tags: javascript, html

I recently starting learning JS and for some reason I cannot get *getElementByClassName* to work for me. Here's my code.

```js
//variable to store the ID h1
var id = document.getElementById("first");
//variable to store the class h1
var cs = document.getElementsByClassName("second");

//coloring the id 'first'
id.style.color = "red";

cs.style.color = "blue";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="first">This is an ID</h1>
    <h1 class="second">This is a class</h2>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The element with an ID is changing color but the one with a class isn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that one involves "element" (singular) but the other is "elements".

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection, not a single element, to make it work, use cs[0].style.color = "blue";

Comment: @RyanWilson — While array-like in many ways, the return value is not an array.

Comment: Indeed, it's an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: Edited to use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getElementById** returns one **single** element as you should not have multiple element with the same Id in the DOM.

**getElementsByClassName** returns an **HTMLCollection** as many elements can share the same class name.

try this instead :

```
//variable to store the ID h1
var id = document.getElementById("first");
//variable to store the class h1
var cs = document.getElementsByClassName("second");

//coloring the id 'first'
id.style.color = "red";

cs[0].style.color = "blue";
```

In real life use case you might wanna loop through the array.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton.

Comment: @TylerPolito You should up-vote and Accept (check mark) this answer, then.